# This is a riddle

Tags: riddle, word

- What is searching for letters exactly?
- What do we get when using letters literally?
- What does wordplay finally result in?
- And what is a metaphorical series?

Is there also a word for the combination of the things mentioned above?

Comment: Faith in community!

Comment: What are those downvotes for anyway? Wacky.

Comment: @No.7892142 you missed all the action I guess :p

Comment: @No.7892142 - This question has been closed, reopened, closed again, reopened again, and now got another vote to close. It's the cockpit of Stack Exchange :-p

Comment: @No.7892142 oh by the way, there's 13 downvotes... and 10 upvotes (I believe you can't see them)

Comment: 15 upvotes, 16 downvotes as of now.

Comment: @randal'thor Looks like no one got it - is that possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> WORD

as per the 'word' tag and also the headline.

> Lynch mob, anyone?

*What is searching for letters exactly?*

> 'For letters exactly' -> 'four letters exactly'; the word 'four' does indeed have four letters exactly (in fact it's the only number whose English-language word has that number of *different* letters), so the answer to this line is FOUR.

*What do we get when using letters literally?*

> Well, it does say 'literally'. The answer is simply LETTERS.

*What does wordplay finally result in?*

> The word 'finally' means we should look at the end, so take the word IN.

*And what is a metaphorical series?*

> Sod the metaphor, just take the word SERIES (possibly?). Or a "metaphorical series" is just a SERIES (of some kind... metaphorically).

So we have

> FOUR LETTERS IN SERIES.

*Is there also a word for the combination of the things mentioned above?*

> WORD is a four-letter word. It's a word; it fits the combination of the above clues; the combination is a word and is word and word ... argh, this is getting too meta for me!

Comment: Well done my friend :)

Comment: @avigrail - As 'cop would say, call in the lynch mob!

Comment: xnor still thinks that the solution is not obvious enough and someone finding it won't be sure :D

Comment: I do indeed. I would not have been able to know that of the three solutions posted, this one is the correct one without your accept mark. Still, better now that you've cut out all the distraction text.

Comment: At least you can count to three, that's very good!

Answer (score 5):

The answer is obviously

> letters

Why is that? Well, because:

What is searching for letters exactly?

> Searching for letters is searching for "letters", exactly.

What do we get when using letters literally?

> When we use letters literally, well, we use "letters".

What does wordplay finally result in?

> Wordplay usually results in letters. (Well technically words, but those are made out of, what? Right.)

And what is a metaphorical series?

> Not only metaphorically but actually, letters are a series of symbols (or single letters, if you want to get even more meta)!

Comment: There is some correct stuff in your answer but not all of it. Plus there is a different clue for every line and not 4 times the same :)

Comment: @avigrail There actually is correct stuff in there? I am quite frankly shocked.

Comment: @No.7892142 wouldn't a combination of letters be a "word"

Comment: @Bozman A combination of a couple single letters can also just be considered a "bunch of letters". But yeah, the answer is likely something like "language" or "sentence"?

Comment: @Bozman - maybe the answer is "a single word"?!

Answer (score 3):

Going by the hints given let me try what i think it might be.

What is searching for letters exactly?

> umm Googling i think.

When do we use letters literally?

> Whe we write Mail to someone.

What does wordplay result in?

> results in a Conversation .

And what is a metaphorical series?

> no idea about this though.

Combining these i think you are talking about

> your Gmail account.

also, Internet is a cruel place..

> maybe your account got hacked so you are trying to ditch that mail and create new one.

Comment: Funny idea but that's wrong :p Thanks for finding a riddle in there!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is wrong, but it's oh-so-right.

> What?

What is searching for letters exactly?

> "What" is fo[u]r letters exactly.
>  And *for* letters. (Erm, what? Exactly.)

What do we get when using letters literally?

> What we get when using letters literally.
>  Do we get "what" when using letters literally?
>  We do get "what" when using letters literally.

What does wordplay finally result in?

> Evidently someone goes "WHAT?" because your wordplay confounds them.
>  This wordplay also ends in "What?", since that's the answer.

And what is a metaphorical series?

> "What" occurred four times in a series of metaphors. When? Just now.

This is a riddle

> "This" is certainly a riddle, since "What?" is the answer.